# Events in PHP slim web services

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

I am writing a web service in PHP using the Slim framework. I have a web application and a mobile application which uses the web service. My web application posts some data to the web service and web service writes it to a database. But I also wanted the web service to send a notification to my mobile application.

I assume this is some kind of an event based action. How to perform this for PHP slim web services? Or in general, for a PHP web service?

Comment: You can have the mobile device poll an API to look for a change based on a timestamp... or you would have to use ios push notification to push from the server to mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the symfony2 EventDispatcher component to achieve what you speak of. It's a clean way to, well, implement an event-based architecture. This particular implementation of the mediator pattern can make your code extensible with minimal overhead (and much organization).

Link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

Note: The EventDispatcher can be used independently of symfony2. The above link contains the packagist link of the component.

Edit: If you are a fan of global variables, you could look into the [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) function in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy way to implement a direct event notification from Slim to a mobile device. To do such thing you need to open a socket between device and server so you can send direct notification to the device.

With Slim, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the list/queue pattern and tell the device to periodically ping your web service (like every 30 sec) and check if there is something new in the queue.